# JPA: Многие ко многим не удаляются записи

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня проблема с проектированием базы данных

Есть сущность **User**

```
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    // ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Manager manager;

    // ...

}
```

Она ссылается на сущность **Manager**

```
public class Manager {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> requests;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "manager", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<ParticipantRequest> participantRequests;


    // ...

}
```

Есть сущность **ParticipantRequest**. Ссылается многие к одному к сущность **Manager**

```
public class ParticipantRequest {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ExpertAndRequest> experts;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private Manager manager;

    // ...

}
```

И есть связующая таблица между **Manager** и **ParticipantRequest**

```
public class ExpertAndRequest implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "managerId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Manager manager;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ParticipantRequest request;

    // ...

}
```

Я ожидаю, что при удаление **User**, у меня удалится **Manager** и связанные с ним **ExpertAndRequest**. Но вместо этого ничего не происходит... Ни ошибки, ничего не происходит. Как будто все корректно отработано

Удаляю я так:

```
@GetMapping("/some/url")
@Transactional
@ResponseBody
public ManagerApiResult deleteManager(@RequestParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    if(!this.isUserManager()) {
        return null;
    }

    ManagerApiResult res = new ManagerApiResult();

    Manager manager = this.managerRepository.findOne(id);

    if(manager == null) {
        res.errors.add(String.format("Manager id \"%s\" do not exist", id));
        return res;
    }

    this.userRepository.delete(manager.getUser());

    return res;
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Бьюсь уже 3-й день и все без успехов(

Answer (score 0):

Совсем не уверен ответ ли это на данный вопрос, но существует такая аннотация как

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```